# Positioning of "nie" in sentences

Tags: word-order

My question concerns "nie(mals)" and its positioning in sentences. Does it essentially function just like the particle "nicht" in that regard, e.g., either negating the sentence as a whole or certain elements, etc. Or is it simply an adverb of time and should be treated like one when it comes to word order?

Comment: The question would benefit from one or more concrete examples of sentences where you are unsure. As a native speaker I can't tell you most grammar rules, but I can tell you what sounds good and natural if you give a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

*Nie* is short for *niemals* and it's an adverbial of time. Unlike *nicht*, it occupies a position in the clause. Compare the following simple topic permutations:

> Nie hat er an so etwas gedacht.
>
> Er hat nie an so etwas gedacht.
>
> Er hat an so etwas nie gedacht.
>
> An so etwas hat er nie gedacht.
>
> Gedacht hat er an so etwas nie.

However, as you may roll a main clause up from the end and make that part the topic, the following word order is also allowed:

> Nie gedacht hat er an so etwas.

Don't let that fool you. This is **not** because *nie* is like *nicht*. Consider the following:

> Nie an so etwas gedacht hat er.

That word order is also allowed, though it has the whole remainder of the sentence behind the subject as its topic.